# installing and running Wine

Tags: wine

I used the command

sudo get-apt install wine

to install Wine.

I then tried asking for suggestions on how to run Wine, and somebody suggested I use the command:

```
wine your_exe
```

which produced the following errors:

```
amarth@amarth-AOD270:~$ wine your_exe
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/amarth/.wine'
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x10ee890, overlapped 0x10ee89c): stub
wine: configuration in '/home/amarth/.wine' has been updated.
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\your_exe.exe"
```

But Wine still isn't running....

Comment: What they were saying was to type in `wine` in the terminal, followed by the Windows software you wish to run. For example, if you want to install Quake3 and you have the install disk, you would go to the folder where quake3.exe is, and type wine quake3.exe. You might also want to check winehq.org. They have very good documentation on how different programs run, and how to use wine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently assume that Wine is some sort of Windows environment within Ubuntu. Well, it isn't. The errormessage you present clearly shows that Wine was running in thus particular case. The problem here is that Wine can't find the executable to run. To solve this you need to start the terminal and then you can go to the directory where your executable is located and then execute
 `wine your_exe.exe`
or from within any directory in the terminal you can execute
`wine "/path_to_your_exe/your_exe.exe"`.
Make sure you adjust these commands to reflect the actual location and name of your executable.
There's also a chance that your executable can't be run by a plain Wine install.